# If a variable is enclosed, and an instance sets a property with the same name, where does the property go?

Tags: javascript, closures, encapsulation

Most of us know that JavaScript has no sense of "private" properties, but that behavior can be emulated through the use of closures:

```
var Car = function () {
    var name = 'Tesla';
    var wheelCount = 4;

    this.getName = function () {
        return name;
    };
    this.getWheelCount = function () {
        return wheelCount;
    };
    this.setName = function (newName) {
        name = newName;
    };
    this.setWheelCount = function (newCount) {
        wheelCount = newCount;
    };
};

var myCar = new Car();
console.log(myCar.name); // undefined
```

That all makes sense to us that know about how JavaScript closures work. However, the following will work:

```
myCar.name = 'Corvette';
console.log(myCar.name); // 'Corvette'
```

But then if you call the function from the prototype, the enclosed variable is still used

```
console.log(myCar.getName()); // 'Tesla'
```

When you call `myCar.name`, you're adding a new property to the object. Is it just the entire point of using `this` when declaring the `getName` (etc) functions inside the `Car` definition to make the differentiation between the enclosed `name` inside the `Car` declaration versus the `myCar.name`?

I have a feeling that I know the answer to this, but I would like to be certain. Plus, I think this would be something invaluable to other people getting an advanced grasp on how JavaScript enclosures work.

Comment: There is no `Car.name` - those local variables inside the constructor are not properties of any visible object. The closure is (somewhat) like an anonymous object to which no reference can be generated.

Comment: You're right. I was using `Car.name` as the simplest way to explain the differentiation. I will clarify better for what is actually there.

Comment: *Is it just the entire point of `this`* -- well, which `this`? The example uses `this` only for the accessors.

Comment: Thank you, I'll clarify again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just the entire point of using `this` when declaring the `getName` (etc) functions inside the `Car` definition to make the differentiation between the enclosed name inside the `Car` declaration versus the `myCar.name`?

Yes.

`this` (or `myCar`) is the object, on which you put the *properties* that you want to have it (in this case all those methods). If you want to use properties, you must use a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

`var name` is just a local *variable* in the constructor function, which is accessed by closure from the object's methods.

Or, to answer your title question:

> If a variable is enclosed, and an instance sets a property with the same name, where does the property go?

The property goes *on the object*. It doesn't interfere at all with the variable, which is located *in the scope* of the `Car` constructor invocation.

Answer (score 1):

In your example car function is a constructor function. When a constructor function is called with new operator, a new object is created and "this" gets bound to that new object. And "this" is returned from the function even if there is no return statement (unlike non-constructor functions that returns undefined if nothing is returned)

So When you called new Car() a new object got created and as "this" was bounded to this new object, the new object got 4 functions that you defined in Car function (getName, getWheelCount, setName, setWheelCount)

The name variable defined in Car function is not bounded to "this", it is bounded to Car's function scope. When car function returned "this", because of closure getName() still has access to function's name variable.

Now when you tried myCar.name, as the new object that was created does not have any variable called name, it printed undefined.

On doing myCar.name = 'Corvette', as no property named name was found in myCar,new property was created with name "name" and value "Corvette" (javascript creates a new property if it is not already existing in case of write operations, for read operations prototype chain is followed)

But surprisingly myCar.getName() still prints "Tesla" and not Corvette, because though the variable names are same they are in diffrent scope.The one that is referred by getName was part of Car function scope and is bounded to getName via Closure, but the name ("corvette") that you added belongs to new object that you created.

The purpose of "this" is to add the functions/variables defined inside constructor function to the object that you are going to create through that constructor function.

Hope it helps.